# How to round Magento 2 special prices?

Tags: magento2, price, special-price

What I am trying to achieve is that, I have SALE on an item I've managed to display the **Regular Price** and the **Special Price** But let's say I have a product which has regular price of **319.00** I would like to apply 20% discount on this product which results in a price **255.20**. What I want is to round the end number. If the value is below .50 to go to the lower number and if the value is above .50 to go to the bigger number. Is this possible without buying an expensive module. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've also gone through this problem, Please use this plugin, I hope this will help you. For Me this is best solution and tested in 2.3 and working fine.

[Price Decimal Precision Free Magento 2 Extension](https://github.com/lillik/magento2-price-decimal)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but isn't this plugin just hiding the decimal part of the price?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution for my issue. I am using Magento 2.3.2. Tried this plugin
[Magento 2 Price Round plugin](https://github.com/karliuka/m2.Price) Everything is working perfect so far.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified a method convert of file `Magento\Directory\Model\Currency`

declaring a plugin, file `Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"> 
<type name="Magento\Directory\Model\Currency">
    <plugin name="vendor_module" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\Currency" />
</type>
```

plugin model, file `Vendor/Module/Model/Plugin/Currency.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;

class Currency
{
    public function aroundConvert($subject, $proceed, $price, $toCurrency = null)
    {
        $price = $proceed($price, $toCurrency);     
        // you logic
        // warning ... logic affects the price of shipping  
        return $price;
    }
}
```

Also see [Complete code](https://github.com/karliuka/m2.Price) on GitHub